# Simple Math max function in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, math, stored-procedures

How to find the maximum of two explicit values in MySQL? Something like MAXIMUM(1, @foo).

There are group functions like MAX, MIN, AVG, etc that take column name as an argument and work with result sets. Is it possible to convert two explicit values to a result set and use those functions? Some other ways?

P.S.: I need a max function for one of my stored procedures.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> How to find the maximum of two explicit values in MySQL? Something like MAXIMUM(1, @foo).

Use the [GREATEST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) function:

```
GREATEST(1, @foo)
```

...will return whichever value is larger - if 1 is larger than the value in @foo, you'll get 1.  Otherwise, you'll get whatever value is in @foo.  Also, it's **not** an aggregate function.

The alternative would be to use a CASE statement:

```
CASE WHEN 1 > @foo THEN 1 ELSE @foo END
```

...because CASE is ANSI standard - that will work on Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server, Postgres...

Comment: Opposite is [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) LEAST

Answer (score 2):

You can use `IF(1 > @foo,1,@foo)`